Flag records 7 days from the previously identify record
I'm looking to flag those rows that are >= 7 days from the previously identified record.
From the example below, the valid rows are 4-13-2022, 4-20-2022 and 4-28-2022
drop table #tmp1
create table #tmp1(
membernum int,
sevrfromdate date
)

insert into #tmp1
values (1000016, '4/13/2022')
insert into #tmp1
values (1000016, '4/15/2022')
insert into #tmp1
values (1000016, '4/20/2022')
insert into #tmp1
values (1000016, '4/22/2022')
insert into #tmp1
values (1000016, '4/23/2022')
insert into #tmp1
values (1000016, '4/28/2022')

This is my failed attempt to flag the records.
select *,
case when datediff(d,coalesce(lag(sevrfromdate) over (partition by membernum order by sevrfromdate),
                        dateadd(d, -7, sevrfromdate)), sevrfromdate) > = 5 then 1 else 0 end as lasttm,
                        lag(sevrfromdate) over (partition by membernum order by sevrfromdate)
from #tmp1

desired output

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Note the code formatting I added, which you removed with your edit.

Could you explain how your logic should work? (it is not clear what you mean by 'previously identify record'); your attempted query marks each row as 1 if its servfromdate is more than 4 days later than the servfromdate of the previous row (lag). I don't understand how you marked your rows with 1.

What is a "identify record"?

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result.

Note that tables have rows, not records.

I have a feeling you want to have a way of getting rows that are >= 7 days from the previously identified row recursively, in that case LAG cannot be used and you probably need a CTE

The "identified record" would be the next record >=7 days.  In the sample above, the next identified record would be 4/28/2022.

28 - 23 = 5, which is less than 7 days.

The comparison will not be made to the 4-23-2022 but from the prior identified row for 4/20/2022.  So from 4/20/22, the next valid row is 4/28/2022

As pointed above by  @siggemannen, there we can use recursive query to select first and next flagged date.

First, calculate possible next date for every row - min(sevrfromdate) where this date>=7 days from current row date.
Then we take first row (obviously flagged) and recursively take other flagged rows.
Finally, join source table with recursive query output.

See example



membernum
sevrfromdate




1000016
2022-04-13


1000016
2022-04-15


1000016
2022-04-20


1000016
2022-04-22


1000016
2022-04-23


1000016
2022-04-28



with t as(
  select membernum, sevrfromdate
    ,(select min(sevrfromdate)
      from #tmp1 t2 where t2.membernum=t.membernum
       and t2.sevrfromdate>=dateadd(d,7,t.sevrfromdate)
  )  nextdate
  from #tmp1 t

)
,r as(
  select 0 lvl, membernum, sevrfromdate
    , nextdate
  from  t
  where sevrfromdate=(select min(sevrfromdate)
             from #tmp1 t2 where t2.membernum=t.membernum) 
  union all
  select lvl+1,t.membernum, t.sevrfromdate
    ,t.nextdate
  from r inner join t on r.membernum=t.membernum
     and t.sevrfromdate=r.nextdate
) 
select t.membernum, t.sevrfromdate
  ,case when r.sevrfromdate is not null then 1 else 0 end flag
  ,r.nextdate as next_date
from #tmp1 t
left join r on r.membernum=t.membernum
   and r.sevrfromdate=t.sevrfromdate





membernum
sevrfromdate
flag
next_date




1000016
2022-04-13
1
2022-04-20


1000016
2022-04-15
0
null


1000016
2022-04-20
1
2022-04-28


1000016
2022-04-22
0
null


1000016
2022-04-23
0
null


1000016
2022-04-28
1
null



fiddle
Recursive query result



lvl
membernum
sevrfromdate
nextdate




0
1000016
2022-04-13
2022-04-20


1
1000016
2022-04-20
2022-04-28


2
1000016
2022-04-28
null




Works like a charm.  Thanks!

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        membernum,
        sevrfromdate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY membernum ORDER BY sevrfromdate) AS rn
    FROM #tmp1
),
FlaggedRecords AS (
    SELECT
        c1.membernum,
        c1.sevrfromdate,
        CASE
            WHEN c1.rn = 1 THEN 'True'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, c2.sevrfromdate, c1.sevrfromdate) >= 7 THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
        END AS Is7days
    FROM CTE c1
    LEFT JOIN CTE c2
    ON c1.membernum = c2.membernum
    AND c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
),
TrackingCTE AS (
    SELECT
        membernum,
        sevrfromdate,
        Is7days,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Is7days = 'True' THEN sevrfromdate END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY membernum ORDER BY sevrfromdate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS LastTrueDate
    FROM FlaggedRecords
),
FinalFlagging AS (
    SELECT
        membernum,
        sevrfromdate,
        Is7days,
        LastTrueDate,
        CASE
            WHEN Is7days = 'True' THEN 'True'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, LastTrueDate, sevrfromdate) >= 7 THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
        END AS FinalIs7days
    FROM TrackingCTE
)
SELECT membernum, sevrfromdate, FinalIs7days, LastTrueDate
FROM FinalFlagging
ORDER BY sevrfromdate;

This query will give you the desired output. FiddlerOutput

If I change the record set. the code does not return the correct flags.
INSERT INTO ##tmp1 (membernum, sevrfromdate)
VALUES
(1000016, '2022-04-13'),
(1000016, '2022-04-15'),
(1000016, '2022-04-20'),
(1000016, '2022-04-22'),
(1000016, '2022-04-23'),
(1000016, '2022-04-30');

In this case the correct values are 2022-04-13, 2022-04-20, 2022-04-30

did you tried with more test case?
